# unable to see nginx logs

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to confirm my logs are in json format but I cannot even see one log. I am using `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: test_site
    volumes:
      - /Users/mikeJ/Desktop/test-logs/access:/tmp/logs/access
      - /Users/mikeJ/Desktop/test-logs/error:/tmp/logs/error
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped      
    ports:
      - "8040:8040"
```

ngnix.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  include    mime.types;
  sendfile on;
  access_log on;

 log_format json_combined escape=json
   '{'
     '"time_local":"$time_local",'
     '"remote_addr":"$remote_addr",'
     '"remote_user":"$remote_user",'
     '"request":"$request",'
     '"status": "$status",'
     '"body_bytes_sent":"$body_bytes_sent",'
     '"request_time":"$request_time",'
     '"http_referrer":"$http_referer",'
     '"http_user_agent":"$http_user_agent"'
   '}';

  server {
    listen 8040;

    error_log /tmp/logs/error/error.log warn;
    access_log /tmp/logs/access/access.log;

    server_name localhost;
    location /{
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      index index.html;
    }

  location ~ ^/test/footer {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    expires 5m;
    access_log on;
}
```

}

dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.15.0-alpine

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copying nginx configuration file
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

# setup nginx caching
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/nginx/cache

#create directory for logs
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/logs/error
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/logs/access

#adding footer file
ADD footer /usr/share/nginx/html/footer

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8040
```

I even `ssh` into the container and nothing is there.

from inside the container

```
 # ps aux | grep nginx
    1 root       0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
    7 nginx      0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you confirm if the nginx.conf is correct? 
It seems that the nginx process does not have permissions to write to the directory created.

```
ps -eo "%U %G %a" | grep nginx
```

Run the command above to learn the user. It is `nginx` in your case.
Change the owner and group for the log directory and reload the nginx service.

```
#create directory for logs
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/logs/error
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/logs/access && \
    chown -R nginx:nginx /tmp/logs/

#adding footer file
ADD footer /usr/share/nginx/html/footer
```

Check the logs folder post accessing one of your URLs.

Comment: `ps: bad -o argument '%U %G %a', supported arguments: user,group,comm,args,pid,ppid,pgid,etime,nice,rgroup,ruser,time,tty,vsz,stat,rss`

Comment: ```/ # ps -e "%U %G %a" | grep nginx 
    1 root       0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
    7 nginx      0:00 nginx: worker process
   17 root       0:00 grep nginx
```

Comment: Great. Your nginx service is running under the user `nginx`. I have updated my answer to point the changes to be done in the docker file.
Please make the changes in your docker file accordingly and check the same.